# send linux console through serial

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, serial-port

What I want to do is connect my PC to my terminal a DEC vt320 and be able to output the Linux console to it and for me to be able to type commands into the terminal and for it to send a reply on the screen.
I wanted to connect to stuff from telnet but I don't know how to do it through serial.
my serial connection is /dev/ttyS0

Comment: Do you want `the` linux console, or just `a` bash shell?

Comment: Which Linux version are you using?  The answer may change, depending on distro.

Comment: I'm using Linux mint and it doesant matter if its the shell or the console. which ever ones easier to output

Comment: Which version of mint?

Comment: It is linux mint 19.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Mint 19.3 uses `systemd`, so unless Mint has modified the `systemd` configuration from what the parent distributions (Ubuntu and ultimately Debian) have, the following commands should do the job.

To start up a serial port for terminal-style login access immediately:

```
sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0
```

To make the configuration persist over reboots:

```
sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0
```

After running the first of these commands, a login prompt should appear on the terminal. If it doesn't, press Enter on the terminal once or twice: it can help in detecting the data transfer speed the terminal is operating at.

(The serial port speed is also sometimes known as *baud rate*, although that term would properly apply only to modem connections and similar where digital-to-analog modulation is involved, not to plain digital data transfer.)

This default `systemd` configuration for serial-attached terminals includes serial port speed auto-detection for speeds 115200, 38400 and 9600 bits per second. You can confirm this with command `systemctl cat serial-getty@ttyS0`. It will output the auto-generated unit file for that serial port. Among other things, it should contain this line that starts the actual process that will be managing the terminal:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

If the automatic serial port speed detection does not work well for you, or if you want to specify a speed value that is not included in the default list, you would want to create an *override file* for this systemd service:

```
sudo systemctl edit serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

This command will create the file (if necessary) and open it in an editor for you.

For example, to lock the serial port speed detection to 57600 bps, you would write the following three lines to the override file:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' 57600 %I $TERM
```

The first line specifies that we want to override things in the `[Service]` section of the autogenerated service file, the second specifies that we want to override its `ExecStart` line and not just add another one, and the third line is the new `ExecStart` line with the desired port speed and/or other options for the `agetty` process that manages the terminal.

The traditional name for such a process in the Unix world is `getty`, and Linux typically uses an enhanced (**a**lternative/**a**utobauding) version of it for serial ports: `agetty`.

Comment: An override file will _always_ be needed in this scenario to set the `TERM` environment variable, because the value of that variable inherited from systemd will _always_ be wrong, there being no real terminal that matches the `linux` terminal type, let alone that type matching a DEC VT320 (which it overwhelmingly does not).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer is to just start up a terminal login service on the serial device, as in telcoM's answer.  That does not change the *Linux console*.  Moving the Linux console over to the serial device is simpler to enact, but has more side-effects.

Simply have `console=ttyS0` in the kernel's command line, as supplied to it by a bootstrap loader (probably GRUB in your case).

The systemd-supplied generator will see that and automatically enable a `serial-getty@ttyS0` service.  But, moreover, all actual *console* output, from the kernel and from programs writing to `/dev/console`, will now go to your DEC VT320.

Unluckily, a VT320 *does not support* colour.  (A VT340 does, and only 16 of them.)

This is unlucky because a lot of programs just hardwire ECMA-48 colour control sequences nowadays, including ones that spit out messages to `/dev/console`.  The programs that come in the systemd package all do so, as long as the environment *of process #1*, which they go and read, *does not* contain `TERM=dumb`.  Other programs make different decisions, often based upon *their own* process environments, and some make no decisions based upon terminal *type* at all, because the author never thought that the program's output might be a serial device with a real monochrome terminal.

So you *also* have to ensure that the kernel command line specifies `TERM=dumb`, which is not a correct description of a VT320, and is woefully inadequate.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447098/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475043/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[Manual pages for Linux kernel virtual terminal devices](http://jdebp.uk./Proposals/linux-kvt-manual-pages.html)*.  Proposals.

  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`linux-console`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-console.xml). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`linux-vt`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-vt.xml). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.